# Promise running both success and failure callbacks

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise

I have an array of promises and it's running both the pass and fail callbacks. Can't figure out why.

```
checkForLists: function() {
    var listCheckPromise = [];

    $.each(scmap.lists, function(i, list) {
        listCheckPromise[i] = $().SPServices({
            operation: "GetList",
        listName: list.name,
        })
    })

    $.map(listCheckPromise, function(listPromise, index){
        listPromise.then( pass(index), fail(index) )
    })

    function pass(index) {
      var currentList = scmap.lists[index]
      console.log("PASS:", currentList.name, 'list already created')
    }

    function fail(index) {
      var currentList = scmap.lists[index]
      console.log("FAIL:", currentList.name, 'does not exist. Creating...')
      scmap.createList(currentList)
    }
}
```

Comment: Really not sure how this is off topic.  Maybe poorly worded, but definitely a valid question.

Answer (score 4):

> "*... Can't figure out why.*"

Simple... because you're **calling**

```
$.map(listCheckPromise, function(listPromise, index){
    listPromise.then(
      pass(index), // <-- pass!
      fail(index)) // <- and fail!
})
```

You probably want to try

```
$.map(listCheckPromise, function(listPromise, index){
    listPromise.then(
      function(){pass(index);},
      function(){fail(index);})
})
```

Comment: Okay I see, but then if I don't do it this way, how do I get the array index into the callback?

Comment: Be careful, each time you fire checkForLists(), it will create in memory 2 anonymous function()

Comment: @MichaelRasoahaingo - that's not true. Every call would create 4 + `scmap.lists.length` * 2 anonymous functions. And they will all live as long as necessary and then be collected (or more accurately be *collectable*).

Comment: @Amit good point, but is it a good thing too use anonymous function instead of the function pointer?

Answer (score 2):

When you write this

```
listPromise.then( pass(index), fail(index) )
```

You immediatly execute this 2 functions instead of giving their references

You should write something like this

```
listPromise.then( pass, fail )
```

Comment: How would I get the index into those functions then?

Comment: @Batman could try `bind`, ie `then(pass.bind(null, index), fail.bind(null, index))`

Comment: Great! I forgot the index :D